# SQL & LINQ - Distinct by 2 columns and "reversed values"

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I'm working on a chat system and need to get the inbox data for user 1119. This query should return the last message from each conversation.

A Message entity is made of a sender id (CreateUserId), receiver id (UserId), date (CreateDate) and message text (Desc)

EDIT: A "conversation" is a group of messages sent between two users. For example if the users are 1119 and 1120, the messages in the conversation are the ones with CreateUserId=1119, UserId=1120 OR CreateUserId=1120, UserId=1119.

The current query looks like this:

```
  SELECT MAX(Id) Id, CreateUserId Sender, 
  UserId Receiver, MAX(CreateDate) Date, MAX([Desc]) Message

  FROM [CarSharing].[dbo].[Message]
  WHERE CreateUserId = 1119 OR UserId = 1119
  GROUP BY CreateUserId, UserId)
```

[THE ISSUE: The result gives out two messages from the same person, as the sender and receiver ids are switched. The row with the id 124 shouldn't be there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6mPB.png)

Ultimately, I'd like to implement this with LINQ, so solutions using that are also very welcome !

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and desired results.  What is a conversation?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that a "conversation" is simply a message between two particular people.  That seems to approximate your query.

You can't really do what you want with aggregation.  Because the "max" of the message columns may not be the maximum date/time.  Instead, use window functions:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM (SELECT m.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreateDate DESC, id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM [CarSharing].[dbo].[Message] m
      WHERE 1119 IN (m.CreateUserId, UserId)
     ) m
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

The `ORDER BY` in the windowing clause should be however you define the ordering.  This is guessing that the creation date is first and then the id.